# What is the purpose of the "deep" flag on a watcher in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a web app that is using Vue.js. In my app, I  was creating a watcher. While reading the [API documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch), I noticed that there is a flag called `deep`. My question is, what is the purpose of this flag? It looks like by default, it's set to `false`. However, what happens to the watcher if I set the `deep` flag to `true`?

Answer (score 1):

It detects nested changes to values of the object you are watching. From the docs:

```
vm.$watch('someObject', callback, {
  deep: true
})
vm.someObject.nestedValue = 123
// callback is fired
```

Answer (score 1):

With a deep watcher you can be notified of the changes from nested attributes of the object.

If you watch a `property` declared as: `property: {a: {b: 1}}` without `deep=true` you won't be notified of the changes of `b` but will be notified if you set `deep=true`